# Kustomize + Helm error on chart semver requirements

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, argocd, kustomize

I'm attempting to install the [argo-cd helm chart](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm) with kustomize using the `--enable-helm` feature.

This results in a `kubeVersion` compatibility error. I am confused by this result as the version of kubernetes client and server are both greater than the v1.20.0 required version.

I re-produced this test on a new fresh clean VM which has only ever had the versions shown below.

Where could it be reading in the kubernetes v1.20.0 from and how can I fix that?

##### Error

```bash
kc2admin@kargo:~/argocd$ kubectl kustomize --enable-helm .
error: Error: chart requires kubeVersion: >=1.22.0-0 which is incompatible with Kubernetes v1.20.0
```

##### Versions

```bash
kc2admin@kargo:~/argocd$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.26.0
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: v1.25.4
```

##### Kustomization

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: argocd
helmCharts:
- name: argo-cd
  releaseName: argocd
  valuesFile: values.yaml
  version: 5.16.13
  repo: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
  includeCRDs: true
```

##### Steps to reproduce

```bash
# Create a directory
mkdir argocd && cd argocd

# Create an empty values file
touch values.yaml

# Write the kustomize file
cat <<EOF > Kustomization
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: argocd
helmCharts:
- name: argo-cd
  releaseName: argocd
  valuesFile: values.yaml
  version: 5.16.13
  repo: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
  includeCRDs: true
EOF

# build the manifests with kustomize
kubectl kustomize --enable-helm .
```

---

##### Solution

Update from helm `v3.6.3` to `v3.10.3` as `helm template` is compiled to fallback to an assumed kubeVersion which it was originally compiled for.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but to deployment and kubernetes-helm, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What happens if you ensure there are no valid credentials available? `KUBECONFIG=/dev/null kubectl kustomize --enable-helm .`? Do you see the same error if you run `kustomize build` (assuming you have the standalone `kustomize` command available) instead of `kubectl kustomize`?

Comment: Good suggestion, set KUBECONFIG to /dev/null and got the same error. I also get the same error with the straight kustomize binary build command.

```bash
kc2admin@kargo:~/argocd$ export KUBECONFIG=/dev/null
kc2admin@kargo:~/argocd$ kubectl kustomize --enable-helm .
error: WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location: /dev/null
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is world-readable. This is insecure. Location: /dev/null
Error: chart requires kubeVersion: >=1.22.0-0 which is incompatible with Kubernetes v1.20.0
```

Comment: Go figure, it was my version of helm that caused the issue.

`curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/main/scripts/get-helm-3 | bash`
`kc2admin@kargo:~/argocd$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.10.3"`

and the issue is solved